# Prometheus: How does the rate function calculate per second rate when scrape interval is longer?

Tags: prometheus

From Prometheus documentation rate function does the following:

> rate(v range-vector) calculates the per-second average rate of
>   increase of the time series in the range vector.

How is that possible when scrape interval is longer like `15 seconds`? I mean how does Prometheus estimate "per-second" value when the data points are at least 15 seconds far away?
I assume that the change is estimated to be uniform in the scrape interval but want to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume that the change is estimated to be uniform in the scrape interval but want to be sure.

Yes, that's the case. The units of the return value are per-second.

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm, how rate actually calculates with maybe with some sample?

Comment: The units of a return value ARE NOT PER-SECOND, this is a common deception! They are EXTRAPOLATED relatively to scrape interval!